# How to keep navigating on AMP version only?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I am using a AMP plugin which integrated in the themes named Newspaper,
but this AMP plugin do not support in keeping user browsing on AMP version users navigate to other articles. Can any body help? I find the function is_amp_endpoint() but I dont know how to use it in the case?

Answer (score 0):

AMP Sidebar can help you, i.e. https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-sidebar/

Example: https://gist.github.com/debabratakarfa/bbeb4d5c681290078def38e07b9af2b0